# What does "aí" mean?

Tags: gramática

I understand that it means "there", however I feel like native speakers drop it into sentences and I'm not sure if it might mean something beyond "there"?

I'm specifically asking this because I was watching a [streamer](https://clips.twitch.tv/NiceSingleTermiteOpieOP-gcmdxoGQP3RwoJg_) who said "*você tem planos aí para fim de semana ou dia de semana aí, vulgo hoje?*" and I have no idea what *aí* means in this sentence.

Comment: It means **then**, too. Aí eu fui ao concerto. Then, I went to the concert. Você tem planos aí means Do you have any plans there? The person to whom the question is posed could be far away from the speaker. On the phone: Do you have any plans there [at another place] to do y?

Comment: To me, in the sentence given, especially if not a question, those "aí" would rather mean "currently", "now" (meaning #5 [here](https://www.aulete.com.br/a%C3%AD)), or even be filler words (adding only emphasis, not meaning). If you gave us the wider context (what is said a bit before and after the quote) and/or the link the video (it available), we might be able to judge it better.

Comment: It's covered in Priberam: https://dicionario.priberam.org/a%C3%AD

Comment: Sometimes you can clearly understand the question's meaning without some words... As a native speaker (Brazil), those `aí` are meaningless - don't add anything, they are more like a non-formal way to call your attention than something that you actually need to translate. If I would translate, I would use some slang from streets...

Comment: @stafusa That is a fantastic explanation. Thanks! The part about "adding only emphasis" is very helpful because that is a use that doesn't show up in any  dictionaries (at least that I've seen) and it makes a lot of sense if that is a possible meaning, so thanks a lot! The context was really just him asking a viewer if he has plans and then waiting for an answer. I tried finding the exact spot  where he says the phrase but it was a 10hr broadcast and somewhere the near middle

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Thank you! So it would make sense to simply say "aí" in the phrase above only serves to make the phrase more colloquial and it adds some emphasis to the phrase?

Comment: Yes, @Jimstoke.

Comment: There is no way we can judge really what is meant by ai in your sentence. As for slang from the streets, I would avoid that here. There is no slang from the streets for ai. It is always some time of adverb: so, then, next, there etc. So, if you made up the sentence, you tell us what you meant in English. Many uses of ai are interjections OR discourse markers.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks! Fair enough, I didn't make up the sentence. It was from a streamer asking a viewer his plans on the weekend and I was confused by his use of "aí". That being said, knowing it can act as an almost meaningless filler word (as per the answers above) is helpful

Comment: Jim, he could have been referring to the guy's office or home. Bear in mind, he was seeing him on a screen, right? Be careful throwing around the term filler word here. These are often discourse markers. Even filler words play an important role in spoken language.

Comment: Think of this: I am watching or seeing you and your family sitting at a table at home. I could very well say, even in English; "Got any plans there for the weekend?" "there" would mean "organized plan" or "a plan in place". See what I mean? :)

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, I mean the guy is a 17 year old streamer who used the word "aí" every few sentences and I was just confused because I didn't know it could act as a filler word. But I would guess he has a relatively liberal interpretation of grammar rules and just knowing it can be an empty word that just adds emphasis is helpful.

Comment: Jim, kids don't know grammar. They speak like they speak. Adults often don't either, by the way. In any case, we speak how we speak, which can be more or less sophisticated. And if you have ever listened to a recording of you and a friend talking, you'd hear just as many interjections, re-directions etc. as anybody else....

Comment: @Lambie Exactly! Which is why it can be tricky to get  a feel for a language when you try and learn it academically. There's always a fine line between common liberties some people take in their grammar usage and words people just wouldn't say. I wouldn't randomly say "chair" at the end of a sentence but I might end my sentence with a preposition that shouldn't be there. And then just getting a feel for words that are frequently used "erroneously" and which are not helps understand a language better and obviously "aí" seems to at least sometimes be liable to being used more liberally.

Comment: Goog point, @Lambie You know, it's wrong we're answering in comments — I'll post mine as an answer and later move these comments to chat. Jim, in your quote, if I had to guess, I'd say the first "aí" means "there" as Lambie proposes and the last is just a random repetition, a speech habit, filler word, etc.

Comment: Jim, there are some streaming things in Portuguese.  You won't learn much spoken things from an academic approach. You know, like, this aí thing. That idea of not ending a sentence with a preposition is *really* passé. :) stafusa, OK. I have something to ask you, if you can create a private room and then delete it. :)

Comment: @stafusa I actually found. It is at 2:36:00 https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1207104589